# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string even though result is correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
set dateformat mdy;
    select cast([File Date] as date) as 'test' from gpdetail
```

which produces this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>       Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any idea how to get rid of the error? any help much appreciated have been stuck on this for ages :(

[image: Under the results tab it shows the correct results]

However, Under the results tab it shows the correct results

[image: this is the actual data]

This is the actual data

Comment: you might have a record somewhere that is not formatted correctly thus it can't convert the whole thing. if you got SQL 2012 you try `TRY_CONVERT` and check results to see what row returns null, that will be your 'BAD' record

Comment: Does the following work any better for you: `convert(datetime, [File Date], 1)`

Comment: How many rows are in the table? Just the 6 you have shown us? Probably it is failing on the next row. Show us what that contains.

Comment: The best way to get rid of the error would be to [store your data with the appropriate data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). Any answers to the question you have posted I would consider a work around, rather than a solution. You will continue to have problems until you rectify the underlying issue that the data is not stored correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place to start is with the `isdate()` function:

```
select [File Date]
from gpdetail
where isdate([File Date]) = 0;
```

This may find places where the date does not conform.

If you just want to ignore badly formatted strings, then try:

```
select (case when isdate([File Date]) = 1 
             then cast([File Date] as date) 
        end) as test
from gpdetail
```

Comment: @Thanks sir for the explanation it is working for me also. :)

Comment: One subtle annoyance i've faced is to avoid ELSE clause, otherwise THEN is evaluated unconditionally causing Error 241...